Podman deployment using VS Code
I have the following scenario:

I have a development container on my local machine which I have built using a skeleton file (Dockerfile)
I have several servers on which I could deploy the container on from my machine

Is there a way (plugin etc.) to deploy a locally built container selecting from a list of servers in Visual Studio Code?
Tried several plugins including remote containers etc in vs code. I did not find a plugin which might handle container deployment in VS code. I expect to built a container on my computer, deploy it to a machine from a list of available servers, and work remotely on that container utilizing the server's power.
